# What is the multiprocessing explanation of this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

```py
import time, os 
from threading import Thread, current_thread 
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process 
   
COUNT = 200000000
SLEEP = 5

def cpu_bound(n): 
  
    pid = os.getpid() 
    threadName = current_thread().name 
    processName = current_process().name
    
    print("One") 
  
    while n>0: 
        n = n - 1
  
    print("Two")
```

What is exactly happening? I understood some parts but need an explanation please help someone...

Comment: Umm, a lot of the lines in the example are unnecessary, and there is no multiprocessing going on. In fact, `cpu_bound()` isn't even called, so nothing is going on.

Comment: Okay so what if I do this...                                                                                               
 if __name__=="__main__": 
    start = time.time() 
    p1 = Process(target = cpu_bound, args =(COUNT, )) 
    p2 = Process(target = cpu_bound, args =(COUNT, )) 
    p1.start() 
    p2.start() 
    p1.join() 
    p2.join() 
    cpu_bound(COUNT) 
    cpu_bound(COUNT)

    end = time.time() 
    print('Time taken in seconds -', end - start)